# android: How to pause an audio when another audio is being played?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

I have 2 audio button one is for audio effects and the other one is for audio pronunciation. I wanted to like pause the audio pronunciation when the audio effect is being played and vice versa. But seems like it don't work.

```
 imgfx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                effectsPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                effectsPlayer.setDataSource(getFilesDir()+"/effects/"+fxname);
                effectsPlayer.prepare();
                effectsPlayer.start();

                if(effectsPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    audioplayer.pause();
                    audioplayer.release();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    audio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {

                audioplayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                audioplayer.setDataSource(getFilesDir()+"/audio/"+audname);
                audioplayer.prepare();
                audioplayer.start();

                if(audioplayer.isPlaying()){
                    effectsPlayer.pause();
                    effectsPlayer.release();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if(effectsPlayer != null){
        effectsPlayer.stop();
    }
}
```

I am not sure with my code because it didn't work. Please help me. I would be very happy to hear your suggestions or comments about it that could help me with my project. Thank you so much :)

Comment: What exactly is your problem, so what do you mean by "Does not work"?

Comment: @Twometer like when my I clicked the audio effect or the pronounciation audio, it won't play anymore. I think it is because of the .pause()

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition like below:-

```
 if(audioplayer.isPlaying()){
                audioplayer.pause();
                audioplayer.release();
            }


            if(effectsPlayer.isPlaying()){
                effectsPlayer.pause();
                effectsPlayer.release();
            }
```